# how to pxselect and put it on a var

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hi i am new in acumatica development how can i pxselect a single column and get the result from the bql command can you show me how to do it thank you. This is for the Sales Order I have been searching the web for a sample but its not the same as my problem can someone help me

```
 var str = "10020";

 var cmd = PXSelect < SOOrder , Where < SOOrder.OrderNbr, Equal<
 str>>>;
```

then get a string result from cmd i do not know how to code it properly thank you in advance. i have been trying several codes on how to do it but it always return a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the Acumatica source code for PXSelect and you can find many examples. Just looking at the SOOrderEntry graph there are many and a few using SOOrder.

The Acumatica training should also help to learn the Bql statements and querying results.

Training resource: [openuni.acumatica.com](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/)

Help documents: [help.acumatica.com](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/Help)

To do a simple [PXSelect](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=7d3035af-dac2-47fe-bbe6-b733565697cf) you will have the main DAC (SOOrder in this example) followed by a [Where](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=333f0b35-3b1b-d2e6-9461-7f938893da28) condition. In the where condition for your field you will either use [Current<>](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c19bd9db-77fe-b066-d303-5264bf213410) or [Required<>](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ea358533-f102-21d0-d4b5-cc4795a3cbc0) to pass in your value. Current will take the current value from cache for the given DAC.FieldName. Required<> allows you to pass in a parameter to the PXSelect. Because you are not defining a view and need to select the record you end your PXSelect statement with a .Select() where you pass in the graph to use for the selecting and parameters if any.

If we look at the SOOrderEntry graph there is an example using SOOrder and Current<>

```
SOOrder associatedOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.origOrderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
                And<SOOrder.origOrderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>.Select(this);
```

If we change this to take parameters we would have...

```
SOOrder order = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>,
                And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>.Select(this, "SO", "123456");
```

Then from there you use your returned object. If null there was no value found for the condition. If you are expecting multiple records you can use your statement in a loop or capture in a resultset.

```
if(order?.OrderNbr != null)
{
   //good to go
}
```